# use attr linux command from Java program

Tags: java, attr, runtime.exec

I want to attach meta data to a  file in Unix file system. 
*attr* command lets me do that but 
the command syntax requires the path of the attached variable to be in double qoutes.

```
attr -s outpipe0 "/mnt/FUse/FileB" FileA
```

how can i Use *System.Runtime.exec* in java to run the above command. When ever i try to run using a string array argument I have to give the above *"/mnt/FUse/FileB"* which causes problem in java program as it considers the double quotes as end of string in java. I basically want to send  a string argument which in itself has double quotes.

Can someone suggest a work around .

Thanks

Comment: trivial workaround: write a wrapper Un*x shell script that takes care of correctly calling the *attr* command and call that script from Java (instead of trying to call directly *attr*).  I also strongly advice redirecting any shell script output to either */dev/null* or to a temporary file instead of trying to parse said outputs from Java.  I also advice forking from the external shell process and then *kill -9* the shell process created by Java.  Don't give Java **any** chance to "play smart" with your shell processes.  Oh yup, always call external processes from a spawned Java thread.

Comment: also, never *ever* use anything else but the *Runtime.exec* method call taking a *String[]*.  Don't ever hope using the regular String method call and have Java split your string correctly.  Split your arguments yourself before exec'ing the external process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the quotes within your literal string in Java, like this:

```
"\"/mnt/FUse/FileB\""
```

That will address your question of how to include double quotes in a string, but I doubt it will solve your program.  That's because I doubt the `attr` program actually wants (or accepts) double quotes.  Instead, the shell eats them.  For example, if the command you type in the shell is the one you mentioned, the double quotes will be consumed by the shell before the arguments are passed to `attr`.  So I have doubts that you need the double quotes at all (but if you do, see above).